# shell_exec return NULL

Tags: php, ping, shell-exec

when i run the code

```
shell_exec('ping -c 4 127.0.0.1')
```

it returns NULL, but when I run the same command (`ping -c 4 127.0.0.1`) in ssh, it returns perfectly...

and yes, the script can run shell_exec, I tried `shell_exec('ls')` and it returns correctly, and `shell_exec('ping -V')` returns `ping utility, iputils-ss020927` so ping is being called, but I just get no response...

any help? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

Ping cannot be executed as a user. Root must run `chmod +s 'type -p ping'` in order for users to run ping